# Search entire workbook and fetch out values

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, c#-4.0

In my excel workbook

The first sheet tab contains

```
Number Name Code    Subject
100    Mark ABC Mathematics
101    John XYZ Physics

The second sheet tab contains

Number Name Code    Subject
103    Mark DEF Chemistry
104    John GHI Biology
```

I want to pass the code(which is going to be unique) as a parameter and search the entire excel workbook

and fetch name and subject..

> ie..select name,subject from myexcelworkbook where code='ABC'

I am able to get sheet names, column count etc. but not able to search thro' an entire excel workbook and get the required values

```
        const string fileName="C:\\FileName.xls";

        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        connectionStringBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = fileName;
        connectionStringBuilder.Add("Mode", "Read");

        const string extendedProperties = "Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES";
        connectionStringBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", extendedProperties);
        using (OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString))
       {
            objConn.Open();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlsApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook wb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true);

            Sheets sheets = wb.Worksheets;

            for (int i =1 ; i <= wb.Worksheets.Count; i++)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(wb.Sheets[i].Name.ToString()); - gives sheet names inside the workbook
            }

          Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1); - gives the elements of specified sheet tab
      }

  //To get elements inside a specific sheet of an excel workbook/get column names

        OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + "Sheet1" + "$]", objConn); 

        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(); 

        objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect; 

        DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet(); 

        objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1);

        string columnNames = string.Empty;
        // For each DataTable, print the ColumnName. use dataset.Rows to iterate row data...
        foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in objDataset1.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                if (columnNames.Length > 0)
                {
                    columnNames = columnNames + Environment.NewLine + column.ColumnName;
                }
                else
                {
                    columnNames = column.ColumnName;
                }

            }
        }
```

Can someone share some ideas, so that i can find out the unique data inside the excel workbook and fetch out the needed values based on that? thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you attempted? Your code starts with COM Interop to open a workbook but then switches to using OleDb to fill a DataSet. It is unusual to do both in the same code block. Which approach will you use to find the values you need? If you are filling a DataSet then the Interop seems unnecessary, and you can search or filter a DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the workbooks are as structured as you indicate and you will be querying multiple students then, as @Andy G suggests, you might find it easiest to just get the data into some form of record set then you run your queries on it through Linq or SQL or whatever you prefer. As you aren't wishing to modify the Excel workbook at all this is probably a better approach.

Alternatively, you can use the Excel API, like you were also trying to use. You can enumerate through the worksheets, running a Find on each. A la:

```
internal void GetYourData()
{
    //... code to get the relevant Workbook and relevant/new Excel Application

    Tuple<string, string> pupil;
    string searchTerm = "ABC";

    //Get the cell of the match
    Range match = FindFirstOccurrenceInWorkbook(workbook, searchTerm);
    if (match != null)
    {
        //Do whatever - per your data structure, it is probably easiest to just use .Offset(row, column) property
        pupil = new Tuple<string, string>((string)match.Offset(0, -1).Value, (string)match.Offset(0, 1).Value);
    }

    //... code to do whatever with your results
}

internal static Range FindFirstOccurrenceInWorkbook(Workbook workbook, string searchTerm)
{
    if (workbook == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("workbook");
    if (searchTerm == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("searchTerm");

    Sheets wss = workbook.Worksheets;
    Range match = null;

    foreach (Worksheet ws in wss)
    {
        Range cells = ws.Cells;
        //Add more args as needed - this is just an example
        match = cells.Find(
                what: searchTerm,
                after: Type.Missing,
                lookIn: XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas,
                lookAt: XlLookAt.xlPart);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cells);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws);
        if (match != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wss);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    return match;
}
```

Also, you can't use COM objects like you use without generating orphaned references -> this will prevent the Excel application from closing. You need to explicitly assign all object properties you want to use like Workbook.Worksheets to a variable then call System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject(object) when the variable is about to go out of scope.

Comment: Thanks.

.Offset(-1, 0).Value is throwing error, i used get_Offset

new Tuple<string, string>((string)match.get_Offset(-1, 0).Value, (string)match.get_Offset(1, 0).Value);

However the output results are not correct, let me check again.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 whoops - I put what should have been a column offset as a row offset and vice versa. (just change Offset(-1,0) for Offset(0,-1) etc). Also I use NetOffice not the Microsoft PIAs so get_Offset may be what you need. .Offset certainly works for me.

Comment: Thanks, instead of Offset(0, 1).Value, anyway i can pass column name, anytime the output result could change ?